# How to Render Unity UI Canvas in between two 3D Objects?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, oculus

I have a world space UI canvas which I want to render on top of some background 3D objects. So far I have achieved it by setting `Order in Layer` property of canvas to `1`. Now the canvas is rendered on top of 3D Objects in background. For fading effect I am using a shader (**Unlit Transparent Color**) on shpere which is provided by Oculus as:

```
Shader "Oculus/Unlit Transparent Color" 
{
    Properties 
    {
        _Color ("Main Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
    }

    SubShader 
    {
        Tags {"Queue"="Transparent" "IgnoreProjector"="True" "RenderType"="Transparent"}
        LOD 100
        Fog {Mode Off}
        Cull Off  // Cull off makes 3D object render from both inside and outside. 
        ZWrite Off
        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
        Color [_Color]

        Pass {}
    }
}
```

Fader is working fine with everything except the canvas which has Order in Layer = 1. Due to this setting UI always appear on top of everything no matter how close I place the fader sphere to the camera.

Is there any kind of settings which can be used to control rendering of 3D Objects on top of a canvas. Like we have Order in Layer for Sprite Renderer and UI Canvas?